# how to change font family for new window

Tags: javascript, font-family

I want to print the content of a div and have the following solution:

```
w=window.open();
w.document.body.style.fontFamily = 'Arial';
w.document.write(tosend);
w.print();
w.close();
```

Everything works except `fontFamily` is not Arial but (I suppose) a default browser's serif font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I guess you need an important property to set priority to your element**

Try these answers

```
w.document.body.setAttribute('style', 'font-family:Arial !important');
```

else

```
w.document.body.style.cssText = 'font-family:Arial !important';
```

This below thing may not work in IE:

```
w.document.body.style.setProperty("font-family", "Arial", "important");
```

Or you can append an inline styling

```
w.document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('td.EvenRow a {font-family:Arial !important;}'))
```

If nothing works have a class with style property as important and use body.addClass="xx".

Finally have your java script at the end of the HTML which seems to be the best solution than all the above manipulatons.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to double-check:
1) what is the real font family reference you are trying to use. 
2) is it by default provided (in many cases you will have to add font definition resources to you site)

http://www.cssfontstack.com/arial

font-family: Arial,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,sans-serif;

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this.It will temporally transform into your font for print and then again will return to its previous font style .

```
<script>
        function print_font()
        {
            var content = document.getElementById('Pcontent').innerHTML;
            var win = window.open();
            win.document.write(content);
            win.document.body.style.fontFamily="Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif";  
            win.print(); 

        }
    </script>

 <div id="Pcontent">

        <p>Print Me according to your font choice... </p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <a href="#" onClick="print_font()" >Print</a>
```

** Do the same for arial it will work hope so